# Acheiving Slit-Scan in Blender's Compositor

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Is there a way to make a slit-scan technique effect in the Compositor?

[image]

https://www.instagram.com/p/BV3G1tYF5Q-/

Comment: it is not a blender solution but I came across this ffmpeg link a couple of days ago that may give you the result you need, https://oioiiooixiii.blogspot.com/2017/11/ffmpeg-temporal-slice-stacking-effect.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use textures as vectors to distort your image. May be a simplier node setup exists but this works.
[image]